# PHP/mysql site using utf8mb4 won't retrieve emojis correctly from database, despite utf8mb4 being specified everywhere that I can find to put it

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf8mb4

I converted my mysql 5.7 database to utf8mb4 today.

As a test, I've put a poo emoji () in a field, using Navicat.

It displays fine in Navicat, even if I quit and re-open the program.

The problem comes when I retrieve it using PDO in my script and echo it out to the browser; I get ������ (6 diagonal black question markes).

If I copy the character directly into my script and echo that, it works.

So it's not a problem with mysql.

It's not a problem with the font.

It's not a problem with my browser.

It's not a problem with php echoing.

So... it's a problem with PDO?

This is my PDO code:

```
$PDO = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_SERVER.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=utf8mb4', DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false
]);
$PDO->query("SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'");

$rs = $PDO->query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = 1000");  // name has been set to 

while ($a = $rs->fetch()) {
    print_r($a);
}
```

If I check the output of `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';` in php in the browser every output is correctly `utf8mb4`/`utf8mb4_unicode_ci` (apart from `character_set_system` which is simply `utf8`, but I think that's normal?)

What else could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an outdated version of Navicat.  Upgrading from 8 to 11 has fixed my issues.  I realised this was probably the cause when I discovered that emojis INSERTed via php were correctly stored and retrieved in PHP, but wouldn't show correctly in Navicat.

Similarly the opposite was true; emojis set in Navicat would correctly store and retrieve in Navicat, but not in PHP.

Looking at the encoding options for navicat connections, it had a checkbox for "use mysql encoding", but if left unchecked the dropdown of possible options included only utf8, not utf8mb4.  I guess navicat 8 pre-dates that being in common usage.

A quick upgrade, and everything works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks.  I added that to my [long list of charset issues](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#other_computer_languages) with third party software.