# Can't insert strange text to mysql

Tags: mysql, fonts, character-encoding

There is such a text -       
. It is italic and bold, but has no styles. Everywhere I copy and paste this text, it looks the same. I tried to insert it into the mysql table in utf-8 and utf8mb4 and cp1251 encoding, but it did not work. In the table, the entry looks ???????? ????????????? ????????????????????? ????????????? ????????????? ????????????????? ????????. Tried to use mb_convert_encoding but didn't help. What it is? What is the encoding? How to insert it into a mysql? Thanks.

**Upd**
It's work fine with utf8m4. Problem was at old version Navicat i use. It did not display the encoding correctly/

Comment: I don't think styles like italic and bold are represented in character codes.

Comment: @barmar      .

Comment: This *must* be `utf8m4` *all the way through* or it won't render correctly. You need to check all of your configuration settings for connection, server, table and so on to make sure they're aligned.

Comment: Why do you need to carry text formatting into your SQL table? To me, that seems like bad practice.

Comment: @RussJ It's not formatting, these are distinct Unicode characters like ➨ or ! There's a whole host of them mostly for mathematical purposes.  = "MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD ITALIC SMALL A".

Comment: Again, why bother with using the italicized versions of those letters in the DB? Why not just use the regular ones?

Comment: @RussJ It's because people will do this and if your database garbles it then your database has an encoding problem and will likely trash other characters as well.

Comment: I use utf8m4 in table and emoji like  inserted correctly, but not this text

Comment: try use utf8_general_ci   but dont expect to achieve everything.  Character encoding is finite, not infinite.

Comment: Thanks. It's work fine with utf8m4. Problem was at old version Navicat i use. It did not display the encoding correctly/

Comment: `` is hex `F09D9996`, so it definitely needs `utf8mb4`, not `utf8`.  (The clue is the leading `F0`.)  Since you got 4 question marks for each letter, it failed for one of the reasons given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 1):

Old versions of Navicat have an option for utf8, but not for utf8mb4.

In the encoding options for navicat connections, pick "use mysql encoding", not "utf8".

Ref:  [PHP/mysql site using utf8mb4 won't retrieve emojis correctly from database, despite utf8mb4 being specified everywhere that I can find to put it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983996/php-mysql-site-using-utf8mb4-wont-retrieve-emojis-correctly-from-database-desp)